# How to start this proof? The line through $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is the best linear approximation of any function through those points, as $a\to c$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, linear-approximation

I want to prove that the line passing through $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is the best *linear* approximation of any function passing through those 2 points, as $a$ *approaches* $c$.

I'm not sure how to define "best" rigorously, but my hope is that the average value of the line over $[a,c]$ will be as close as possible to that of the function. By average value, I am referring to the Mean Value Theorem of integrals.

Thus, as $|a-b|$ becomes smaller and smaller, the average value of the line should approach that of the function.

It seems pretty obvious visually. I'm not sure what field this is, or how to approach this proof at all. I just happened to come across this in unrelated research. I don't necessarily need a full proof, I just want the first couple steps or so so that I can know the right approach.

I do not mean the tangent line or Taylor polynomial. I mean simply the line passing through $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$. I don't want the tangent line, as then I can't apply the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: I think the first step is to formulate the problem more precisely. What exactly is the line approximating, and in what sense do you think it is the best approximation?

Comment: Best approximation among which approximations? Certainly there are better ones (namely the function itself), or the Taylor polynomial of degree $7$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add linear.

Comment: What do you mean by the average value of the limit over $[a,c]$?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Here are a couple of standard ways to define the notion that a polynomial $p$ is the best approximation of a function $f$ over an interval $[a,b]$: (a) $p$ minimizes the $L^2$ norm $(\int_a^b (f(x)-p(x))^2\,\mathrm dx)^{1/2}$; (b) $p$ minimizes the $L^\infty$ norm $\max_{x\in[a,b]} |f(x)-p(x)|$. Unfortunately, for neither of these is the line though $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ the best among all linear polynomials.

Comment: However, as the interval gets smaller and smaller, all three linear polynomials approach the tangent line to $f$ (at least as long as $f$ is differentiable), so in that sense you could say they all agree.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I'm pretty sure that's what I am looking for. If you post that as an answer, and flesh it out a little more, I would be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your function f(x) passing through the point (a,b) we have what is called the Taylor polynomial namely ,

$$ P(x) = f(a)+ f'(a)(x-a) + f''(a)(x-a)^2/2 + ... +f^{k}(a)(x-a)^k/(k!)$$

Now if you let $x=c$ you get  $$ P(c) = f(a)+ f'(a)(c-a) + f''(a)(c-a)^2/2 + ... +f^{k}(a)(c-a)^k/(k!)$$

Now if you let c approaches to $a$, the higher powers of $(c-a)$ approach zero and you get the tangent line $$ f(a) + f'(a)(c-a)$$

Thus you are approximating $f(c)$ with $$b+f'(a)(c-a)$$

The straight line going through $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is $$y=b+ m (c-a)$$ where $m$ is the slope of the line.

Thus you see the straight line approximation which is indeed the tangent line approximation to the curve is good for smooth curves as far as the approximation is for points very close to $x=a$